Movie with kids and a ghost in a farm from early-mid 90's, possibly late 80s
I watched this at Junior School UK and it has bugged me for many years as to what it's called. And if it's a TV movie it may be quite a long shot identifying it.
My memory of movie itself is a little fragmented as I was only about 9 years old (I'm 29 now) but some scenes stuck in my head because of how brutal they were. 

Estimated year I watched it: 1995 - 1996
Year of film: Unknown, possibly late 80s - early-mid 90s
Setting: The location is on a Farm
Characters: Group of teenage kids visiting the farm possibly on a school trip
Language: English / Possibly American

Key plot points I remember:

The kids separate looking around the farm and run into hazardous scenarios. 
A shot of a gravestone is shown where a male ghost sits up out of the grave and heads into the farm.
There is a flashback scene looking back at the past where a similar aged child has something happen to them.
The particular flashback that sticks in my head is where there is a piece of machinery with a spinning wheel. A girl goes up to it and in the proceeding events her arm is torn off.
The shot of the grave with the ghost rising is seen a few times in correlation to the actions of the present day kids.
The last tragic event flashback I believe is of a kid drowning in the past. Then in the present day, a child has a similar faint but in a rice container instead. I believe they are rescued in the process maybe using a tractor to break the container?

In the end, I think the ghost was trying to warn them. And to avoid the things that happened in the past from happening in the present day. 
I know its a long shot but it would be amazing if someone else knows the film I'm even talking about.

What do you mean by "cut-scene?" It usually relates to video games, or deleted scenes, which wouldn't have been in the movie. Can you clarify this?

Apologies I have changed the wording to flashback instead.

I have only gone and found it! I thought I would try a health and safety search and came across The Apaches 1977. Then on a Forum someone described the exact film with the male ghost.
Anyway here it is, its called Never Rest 1990 & its a short farm safety film. I was shown this when I was 8 or 9 at Junior School check it out.
I'm quite amazed how much detail I remembered: 

 

Dang, late by 17 seconds. ;) And you even found a clip! Well done.

Can't believe I found it haha. But thank you for posting an answer you were bang on the money :)
